# SpringSource STS.ini 3.7.x (Eclipse Mars 4.5.x) Memory Settings

Tags: sts-springsourcetoolsuite

I've seen this question asked a few times but not recently as of July 2015 anyway. I understand at one point in time that adding too much memory in the STS.ini file settings would supposedly cause paradoxical performance issues in STS/Eclipse. I'm not sure if that's still the case and searches are not so fruitful. I've had much frustration with Spring-Source/Eclipse performance over the years and I'm really hoping that the newest version(s) are addressing those issues now that PCs have 64-bit operating systems and higher memory. In my case, I have a 6-core processor, 64-bit Windows 8 and 16 GB of memory, and yet I still have to wait for various tasks. Here is my attempt at my STS.ini file. I am wondering if you have suggestions on how I can make the most of my 16 gigs of RAM without tripping up the IDE. The only setting I really understand right now is Xmx, which should be the memory given to Eclipse. I'd love to know how to max them all out and back them down as needed. I'm sort of surprised this isn't something the the IDE Properties wouldn't have a UI for - to take the guess-work out of the ranges. Thanks so much for your help!

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.100.v20150511-1540.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.300.v20150602-1417
-product
org.springsource.sts.ide
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
384M
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
-Xms256m
-Xmx4G
-Xmn128m
-Xss1m
-XX:PermSize=128m
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-Xverify:none
-Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.IEVersion=10001
```

Comment: I am not sure if the performance issues that you are facing are all related to memory settings or things like this. Did you actually observe STS running out of memory or doing a lot of garbage collection while running, so that the 4Gb of heap is not enough?

Comment: I also would love to work with you in more detail to figure out what the perfromance issues exactly are - and fix them for upcoming versions. Therefore I would like to recommend toi open an issue in https://issuetracker.springsource.com/browse/STS. Following on with that, I will ask you to maybe record a profiling session for me to do a deeper analysis of the issues. That would be great. Thanks!!!

Comment: Hi Martin, Sorry to not reply sooner. We did discover a network issue at a one point which was causing some of our latest issues around communicating with svn server and maven nexus server. It would cause STS to bog down during related tasks. Turning off rebuild automatically seams to always help too. I still would love to better understand each of these many settings and how high they can be set for optimal performance. Ideally, it's too bad they can't be set through a UI feature in Eclipse. I am now doing a brand new build of STS 3.7.0.RELEASE on Windows 10. Will report back if issues exist.

Comment: ok, great, thanks for coming back o this. In addition to those comments I would like to highlight that 4G of heap space sounds a lot to me, much more than you should need. 2GB should be way more than enough. I would also recommend to add "-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC" to make the garbage collector more efficient when working with those heaps. If you still observe obsessive memory usage, you should think about capturing a heap dump somewhere for us to analyze.